# Spring When saving data into DB everything is null

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am trying to save user input into Database but when I do everything is null. The picture below is the state of my database right now. The first line is hard coded information.
[image]

I am taking user input from a HTML form. The code for that is below.

```
<form action="addResults" modelAttribute="results">

 <label for="ttn">TTN: </label><br>
 <input type="text" id="ttn" name="fname"><br>
<label for="f">Full Name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
<label for="email">Email:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="email" name="lname">
<label for="age">Age:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="age" name="lname">
<label for="gen">Gender:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="gen" name="lname">
<label for="add">Address:</label><br>
 <input type="text" id="add" name="lname">
<label for="post">Post Code:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="post" name="lname">
<label for="res">Result:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="res" name="lname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

This is the controller code

```
//Add new results
@RequestMapping(value = "/addResults", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newHotel(@Valid @ModelAttribute TestResults results, BindingResult result) {
    trRepo.save(results);
    return "start";
}}
```

And this is the Java Class where all the annotations are.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String email;
private String fullname;
private int age;
private String gender;
private String Address;
private String PostCode;
private String TTN;
private String TestResult;
public TestResults() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public TestResults(String email, String fullname, int age, String gender, String address, String postCode,
        String tTN, String testResult) {
    this.email = email;
    this.fullname = fullname;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.Address = address;
    this.PostCode = postCode;
    this.TTN = tTN;
    this.TestResult = testResult;
}
```

So what I am trying to do is populate the database with the fields above with all the data from a user input but currently it is getting saved as null. Has anyone got any ideas about how to fix this.

Comment: I think you need to ensure the data is posted in the code and html. This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862551/spring-3-mvc-form-not-saving-data-in-database.

Comment: The `requestMethod` should be `POST` not `GET`

Comment: @RandyCasburn when i use POST and remove GET i get the following error "Message Request method 'GET' not supported" thats why I had that code up there

Comment: @ILally I have tried following that but it still comes through as Null?

Comment: That error means your server is blocking POST requests. Are you using Spring Boot? What server? (Heroku by any chance)?

Comment: You may also need to configure both: `method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}`

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am using spring boot I'm not really sure what server I am using, Maybe Tomcat on localhost. I'm using gradle as well. Is there any way I can find out what server I am using.

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot you're using embedded Tomcat.

Comment: what annotations do you have on the controller class declaration?

Comment: The controller class defenition is @Controller public class MainController {

Comment: field name should always starts from lowercase. follow java naming convention n method call should be POST in your case

Comment: I sorted it now, I changed all my field names to lowercase and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Your entity doesn't have a @column annotation in order to map it to the columns present in database :

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@column(name = "email")
private String email;
```